# Missing $ inserted \end{frame}

Tags: tables, beamer

I am writing a beamer. I got lots of Missing $ inserted \end{frame}. Where I havent missed any $. this is the part of the code I have used where similar error is shown

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{normalsize}
Sectors and angle of each sectors are shown in Table 1:

\begin{table}[hb]
\caption{Sectors and Sector Angle}
\label{Sectors and Sector Angle}
\vspace{0.35cm}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline \textbf{SECTOR} & \textbf{DEGREE} \\ 
\hline Sector 1 & -30\leq\theta_s\leq30 \\ 
\hline Sector 2 & 30\leq\theta_s\leq 90 \\ 
\hline Sector 3 & 90\leq\theta_s\leq 150 \\ 
\hline Sector 4 & 150\leq\theta_s\leq-150 \\ 
\hline Sector 5  & -150\leq\theta_s\leq-90 \\ 
\hline Sector 6 & -90\leq\theta_s\leq-30\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{normalsize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: The right column should be in math mode `$...$`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you are adding some code, you can either leave 4 whitespaces to each line or by selecting the code and clicking `{}` button to mark it as a code. That's what I've just did.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The right column in your table consists mainly of math formulas, so you need to add `$` to the column specification. Instead of inserting `$..$` at each cell, you can save typing by modifying the column specification as `\begin{tabular}{|c|>{$}c<{$}|}`.

A better visual alignment is to make the term `theta_s` at the center of the column, this is achieved via `\begin{tabular}{|c|>{$}r<{$} @{${}\leq\theta_s\leq{}$} >{$}l<{$}|}`. Now we have split the right column into two `r` and `l` and the expression `{}\leq\theta_s\leq{}` at the center. The two `{}` are there just to correct spacing around the binary operator `\leq`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{normalsize}
Sectors and angle of each sectors are shown in Table 1:

\begin{table}[hb]
\caption{Sectors and Sector Angle}
\label{Sectors and Sector Angle}
\vspace{0.35cm}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|>{$}r<{$} @{${}\leq\theta_s\leq{}$} >{$}l<{$}|}
\hline \textbf{SECTOR} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{DEGREE}} \\ 
\hline Sector 1 &  -30 &   30 \\ 
\hline Sector 2 &   30 &   90 \\ 
\hline Sector 3 &   90 &  150 \\ 
\hline Sector 4 &  150 & -150 \\ 
\hline Sector 5 & -150 &  -90 \\ 
\hline Sector 6 &  -90 &  -30 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{normalsize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you take a moment to explain what your code does? I certainly understand it, but maybe OP just sees a solution that works magically (given that OP stumbles over a missing `$…$`).

Comment: A small suggestion: the split `r` and `l` columns should still be set in math mode, so that you get proper minus signs for the negative numbers, instead of hyphens.  (Compare the typesetting of `\fbox{$-150$}` and `\fbox{-150}` to see the difference.)

Answer (score 5):

AboAmmar has explained how to fix the problem; this is a complementary answer, which explains the error message.

TeX generates the same error message, `Missing $ inserted`, for two very different circumstances:

- You left out the *closing* `$` on a math expression.  This error gets reported at the point where you leave the "group" construct or paragraph that contains the opening dollar sign for the math expression.
- You left out the *opening* `$`.  This error gets reported at the point where you use a TeX primitive that is only allowed in math mode.

In both cases, the place where the `$` should have been is almost always some distance before the place where TeX reports the error.

The error message you got *looks like* it's complaining about a missing closing `$`, because it's associated with `\end{frame}`, but the mistake you actually made is to write

```
-30\leq\theta_s\leq30
```

instead of

```
$-30\leq\theta_s\leq30$
```

(and similarly for the other rows) because `\leq`, `\theta`, and the subscript character `_` can only be used in math mode.

I don't know why you only got a complaint at the point of `\end{frame}`; probably Beamer and/or the table machinery are doing something which causes the error not to be reported promptly.

Comment: Your explanation helped me to figure out that \widehat{=}
should also be wrapped into $ sings.