# Space missing in Itemize text

Tags: beamer

I am using the following line to itemize and describe a simple equation:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Terrestrial carbon cycle
$$NEE = -NPP + R_h = -GPP + R_eco$$
with NEE (Net Ecosystem Exchange), NPP (Net Primary Productivity),R_h  (Heterotrophic Respiration), R_eco (Ecosystem Respiration)
\end{itemize}
```

But this produce something I don't understand:
[image]

why some space are well written and some other ones are totally not respected and why is my text going out of the frame?

Comment: We've had this before - your use of `R_h` without explicitly using math mode - `$R_h$` - causes TeX to insert the missing `$`, with everything else following being set in math mode (hence the *italic* formatting).

Comment: I assume you want `R_{eco}` rather than `R_eco` -- the subscript should consist of "eco", not just "e", right?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Missing `$` inserted `\end{frame}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/376851/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the following layout more to your liking? It uses a `tabular` environment to list the variable names and their meanings. (Aside: I assume the reason "GPP" isn't defined on this slide is that it's already defined, on an earlier slide, right?)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Terrestrial carbon cycle
\[
NEE = -NPP + R_h = -GPP + R_{eco}
\]
with

\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
$NEE$     & Net Ecosystem Exchange\\
$NPP$     & Net Primary Productivity\\
$R_h$     & Heterotrophic Respiration\\
$R_{eco}$ & Ecosystem Respiration
\end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```